# NameError when running .py file from CMD Windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, interpreter, nameerror

I am trying to run a .py file created in a text editor from the CMD line in Windows 10. Here is my very simple code:

```
def main():
    print 'It works!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run from CMD line, which is already in python 2.7 mode, i type

```
pytest.py
```

which is the name of the file.  However, now the CMD line says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pytest' is not defined
```

[image: CMD Screenshot]

[image: CMD Screenshot 2]

Comment: `pytest.py` is not inside your user folder... I would highly suggest you download PyCharm or use IDLE. Command prompt interfaces are not designed for beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the file executable or supply it to `python` program to run it

`python pytest.py`

If you are running the file from within the python interpreter, then you need to exit that using `Ctrl + Z` and run it from the command line the way I mentioned above.

**Note:** You will need to change to the directory where `pytest.py` is located in for the above command to work; or you need to supply the path to the file. For example, from your pictures, you are in the root directory i.e. `C:\Users\Eric`; if you open file explorer on windows and navigate to where your file is located, you can right click the file and view properties and this should show you the location. Then in your command prompt, you need to type `cd C:\location\you\just\copied\` then after that you should be able to run the file using the python command above

Comment: This helps a bit, but Eric is running the command from within the Python REPL, not on the cmd prompt/

Comment: I added a screenshot of the CMD to my post, please let me know if that changes your answer...still not finding a solution.

Comment: @smac89 I'm not understanding this, I wrote the code in Atom text editor then saved it as pytest.py.  Then I closed Atom and opened CMD prompt and tried to run it.  I don't think i have a python interpreter at all.

Comment: @Eric you should just open a cmd.exe command prompt and not start a Python session like you're doing now, type what smac89 wrote directly from your cmd.exe prompt.   You should *not* type ``python`` on your command line first like you're doing on the first line in your screen

Comment: @Eric you do...it's that command you typed called `python`. Reopen the command line, change directory to the folder where the file `pytest.py` lives and type the command I mentioned above

Comment: deleted comment

Comment: You can also Shift + Right-click to "open command prompt here" in windows

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run the `.py` file from the Python interpreter (starting with `>>>`)

So, you need to see `C:\Users\Eric> python pytest.py` to run `python` on your file.

**Or**, you can run only `python`, then you must `import` the file.

```
>>> import pytest
>>> pytest.main()
```

Both cases assume the CMD is at the same directory as your file. If not, you must `cd` to that proper directory first, or use

```
C:\Users\Eric> python C:\Users\Eric\full\path\to\pytest.py
```

Comment: Solved it using your last method.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

When you start a terminal in windows via CMD, you are in the Windows Command Line.
Here you can run your python code by entering

```
python yourpythoncode.py
```

Or you can choose to start the python interpreter by entering just :

```
python
```

In the interpreter you can run your python program by importing it

```
import yourpythoncode
```

If yourpythoncode has a line like

```
if ___name___ = ___main___:
    main()
```

then it is protected from autorunning the code.
So to run your code your still need to call it explicit by entering :

```
main()
```